# How to create dynamic ranges and Improving vba Code

Tags: excel, vba, range, autofilter

I Have a little bit of code (below) that I would like to improve as I find it a little clunky with regards to the ranges as they vary daily, Ideally I would like to use last row instead of using a massive range but, sadly I am not that clever :(

this is the code, if anyone fancies taking a look to improve on I would be greatly appreciative, I think the process is self explanatory (i.e auto filter and copying from one sheet to another)

```
Sub Refresh_click()
Set DbExtract = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set DuplicateRecords = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Sheets("Sheet2").Unprotect
Range("A4:A50").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table22").Range.AutoFilter Field:=23, Criteria1:= _
    "="
DbExtract.Range("F2:F99999").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
DuplicateRecords.Range("A4:A50").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("Sheet2").Protect
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table22").Range.AutoFilter Field:=23
MsgBox "Log - Updated"
End Sub
```

Comment: There are tons of articles on the internet how to improve your code. If someone just do it for you, you will never learn and understand it. Just try and learn. Path to success is not usually that easy. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in this way, please:

```
Sub Refresh_click()
 Dim DbExtract As Worksheet, DuplicateRecords As Worksheet, lastFRow As Long

 Set DbExtract = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
 Set DuplicateRecords = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

 With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
    .CutCopyMode = False
 End With
 With DuplicateRecords
    .Unprotect
    .Range("A4:A50").ClearContents
 End With

 DbExtract.ListObjects("Table22").Range.AutoFilter field:=23, Criteria1:="="
 
 lastFRow = DbExtract.Range("F" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row of F:F col
 DbExtract.Range("F2:F" & lastFRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
 DuplicateRecords.Range("A4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                                                        :=False, Transpose:=False
 DuplicateRecords.Protect

 DbExtract.ListObjects("Table22").Range.AutoFilter field:=23
 
 With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
 End With
 
 MsgBox "Log - Updated"
End Sub
```

Please, test it and send some feedback. I couldn't test it...

Comment: That's great thank you, I am slowly getting to grips with it, sadly it's quite difficult under the present circumstances working from home and not being able to ask anyone for advice so thank you.  How do I resize the table after updating?  I have tried the obvious based on some of your vba by using "ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table4").Resize Range("A4" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row" but, it returns an error :( .

Comment: 1. Does the above code works as you need? 2. Should I understand that "A4" is inside of a Table? 3. `Resize` does not work in that way... Table Resize **needs a `Range`**, not a long variable. Something like `Range("A4", Cells(Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, "X"))`, where "X" is the Table last column letter...

Comment: Now I am leaving my office. If you need something else, I can see your comment after some hours. But if the above code answered your question, we here tick the code left side check box,  in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue, will know that the code works...

Comment: Hi Yes sorry, that code worked lovely thank you, I have now ticked the tick to make it green, thank you.  Regrettably Range("A4", Cells(Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, "X")) didn't work an error was generated "Compile error: Expected: =

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Using AutoFilter

- Adjust the values in the constants section.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Refresh_click()
    
    Const srcName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const srcTblName As String = "Table22"
    Const srcCol As Long = 6
    Const srcField As Long = 23
    Const srcCrit As String = "="
    Const dstName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const dstFirst As String = "A4"
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Updated As Boolean
    
    With wb.Worksheets(dstName)
        .Unprotect
        Set cel = .Range(dstFirst)
        cel.Resize(cel.Worksheet.Rows.Count - cel.Row + 1).ClearContents
        With wb.Worksheets(srcName).ListObjects(srcTblName)
            .Range.AutoFilter
            Set rng = .ListColumns(srcCol).Range _
                .Resize(.ListRows.Count).Offset(1)
            'Debug.Print rng.Address
            .Range.AutoFilter Field:=srcField, Criteria1:=srcCrit
            On Error Resume Next
            rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy Then
                cel.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                Updated = True
            End If
            .Range.AutoFilter
        End With
        .Protect
    End With
    
    If Updated Then
        MsgBox "Log updated.", vbInformation, "Success"
    Else
        MsgBox "Log not updated.", vbCritical, "Fail"
    End If
    
End Sub
```